# Calculating the probability of success with failure

Tags: probability

Suppose a man tries to fish with $n$ fishing rods,the probability of catching a fish with a fishing rod is $p$
What is the probability of success with n fishing rods?
I know the answer is $m=1-(1-p)^n$
But it's not clear to me why ${\overline {m}}$ (The probability of failing with n fishing rods) can be calculated simply by raising the power to n,But the probability of success cannot be calculated by the power of n
$m=(1-{\overline{p}})^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your confusion stems in the meaning of "success" and "failure". Note that "failure" means "all rods fail" and "success" means "at least one rod succeeds", so you may have a catch with one, two, three... up to $n$ rods. Thus the problem is not symmetric (i.e. invariant/equivariant to the exchange of "success" and "failure").

If you redefine the "success" to mean "all rods succeed", then your formula $m=(1-\bar{p})^n=p^n$ holds.

Comment: Thanks now it's much clearer, I did not think of it in that direction